# how to rewrite invalid images urls with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have an image path like this

```
www.domain.com/i/1.png
```

but this image doesn't exist so i want to rewrite the url to show this image instead

```
www.domain.com/i/0.jpg
```

Comment: @RichardSmith would no tthat just change the image 1.png only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try_files` for such checks. The `try_files` only works if the nginx is used as webserver for **local** files".

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

```
location /i/ {
    try_files $uri /i/0.jpg; 
}

location = /i/0.jpg {
    expires 30s; 
}
```

Comment: it sets the expire header. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires